# Dynamically get MessageBag from ViewErrorBag?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-validation

In my app, I have a generic place for errors in the view that I display simply using:

```
show_messages($errors->getMessages());
```

In the `show_messages` function I parse out the errors in the way I would like them displayed. However I started using some grouping in my forms like `register[email]`.  When I display the errors I use `->withErrors(Input::get('register'), 'register')`.

But now I can't dynamically get the messages becasue `$errors->getMessages()` goes to `default` message bag by default (which in this case is empty).

I can get the errors using `$errors->register->getMessages()`, but that's assuming I know it will be `register`. Looking at the `ViewErrorBag` class I don't see any methods to provide the bag. Is there anyway to do this without altering the current class to get all the bags dynamically or all the messages in each bag dynamically?

Comment: Is this `laravel-4` or `laravel-5`? Are you using both at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this works in Laravel 4, but in Laravel 5 I use `$errors->all()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply iterate over all of the object properties.

```
foreach ($errors as $errorBag) {
    show_messages($errorBag->getMessages());
}
```

While theoretically you would need to check for the property type to know if it's a `MessageBag`, `MessageBag` doesn't have any other public properties.